# Route specific traffic via internet (eth0) to an external IP present on a local interface (wg0)

Tags: linux, networking, routing, tunnel, wireguard

I have `eth0` and a wireguard tunnel `wg0` on my linux system. For some reason I need the external IP `1.2.3.4` to be present on `wg0` so I have added it via: `ip addr add 1.2.3.4/32 dev wg0`. But I need UDP traffic from this system to `1.2.3.4:8000` go via `eth0`/internet. Is it doable?

```
2: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 1.2.3.4/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the original reason you need it to be assigned to wg0?

Comment: @user1686 , an application that I am running expects this IP on a local interface as it binds to it..

Comment: Can you run this application in a network namespace, so you can isolate it from the other applications that would want to connect to 1.2.3.4 over the internet?

Comment: (And please edit your question with new information like the above - comments are not guaranteed to stay around for people later looking at the Q&A).